# Booting Windows on EFI from Linux msdos (invalid signature)

Tags: grub2

My first boot partition table is  ms-dos style.

My fifth disk has GPT table partition  GPT, with:

- EFI partition as first partitiion
- Windows as 4th partition

my **/boot/grub.d/gurb.cfg**  can't boot Windows, I get **invalid signature**. my my file is:

```
menuentry "Windows"{
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    insmod fat
    set root='hd4,gpt1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd4,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd4,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci4,gpt1  5EAE-5C3F
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5EAE-5C3F
        fi
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

Comment: Is Ubuntu installed in UEFI boot mode? You should not mix UEFI & BIOS. And only can if separate drives. And always then have to boot from UEFI boot menu. Once you start booting from UEFI, you cannot switch boot mode, or grub can only boot other installs in same boot mode. If using UEFI, best to only use gpt. Windows requires gpt for UEFI, Ubuntu does not, but really should as UEFI highly recommends gpt.

Comment: Wouldn't `chainloder +1` be enough? https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Chain_002dloading.html

Comment: @JiriB, no, since in the bios version of grub, chainloader means to load another bios boot sector and jump to it, and bootmgfw.efi is not that.

Comment: The boot device is a NVMe drive, windows in is on an HDD drive

Answer (score 0):

You have booted the bios mode grub and are trying to chain load an EFI booting Windows.  You can't do that.  You need to reinstall Ubuntu also in EFI mode.

Comment: Well, you probably mean not Ubuntu but GRUB for EFI.

Comment: How to do it?I Installed My Linux mint on a new drive, I have to reinstall again all???

Comment: @MaxV, you have to boot the installer in UEFI mode.

Comment: The bios is in UEFI mode so I think I installed in UEFI mode...

Comment: @MaxV, do you have a /boot/efi directory?  If not, then you installed in bios mode.