How to boot UEFI windows from BIOS GRUB?
I have one disc partitioned in GPT mode by Windows 10 with whatever sadly Windows 10 installation created there.
/dev/sda1        2048     206847     204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda2      206848     239615      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3      239616 1240977398 1240737783 591.6G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  1240977408 1242068991    1091584   533M Windows recovery environment

sda                                                                                    
├─sda1      vfat   FAT32           AC47-5B68                                           
├─sda2                                                                                 
├─sda3      ntfs                   343642ED3642AFA2                                    
└─sda4      ntfs                   E2C4D5BFC4D5965F   

Then I have a separate disc with Linux installation in MBR with normal grub.
The windows boots fine if it is first boot device in bios. Grub boots fine if the linux disc is the boot device in bios. How do I boot windows from grub?
os-prober generated the following grub.cfg from grub-mkconfig:
menuentry 'Windows 10 (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-AC47-5B68' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod fat
        set root='hd0,gpt1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  AC47-5B68
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root AC47-5B68
        fi
        drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
        chainloader +1
}

However this does not work. Instead of booting windows, the machine is restarted, and after BIOS POST screen I enter grub again. Note: in grub, /dev/sda1 is visible as (hd1,gpt1), but it shouldn't affect anything because search should find it.


That's for MBR, for EFI/GPT it must be: menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-ABCD-EFGH' {     insmod part_gpt     insmod fat     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ABCD-EFGH     chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi } –
Artem S. Tashkinov

Trying the following:
menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-ABCD-EFGH' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod fat
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root AC47-5B68
        chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}

Results in a screen showing:
Booting a command list

Invalid signature

Press any key to continue


That's for MBR, for EFI/GPT it must be: menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-ABCD-EFGH' {     insmod part_gpt     insmod fat     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ABCD-EFGH     chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi }

@ArtemS.Tashkinov Thanks, edited, added result. I think the "invalid signature" is due to beeing in BIOS mode, whereas it wants to run UEFI. But I have no idea about those things.

When in BIOS GRUB, the processor will be in 16-bit compatibility mode, and won't be able to execute the 64-bit code of bootmgfw.efi. Even if it could do that, bootmgfw.efi expects the UEFI API to be available, which is not going to be true in BIOS mode. A BIOS GRUB cannot switch the system from 16-bit BIOS mode to 64-bit UEFI mode, so it is impossible to boot an UEFI OS with a BIOS GRUB.

This question is a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/639457/booting-windows-on-efi-from-linux-msdos-invalid-signature . This is not possible to do. I will be reinstalling windows to MBR.  I can't close as duplicate to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/639457/booting-windows-on-efi-from-linux-msdos-invalid-signature because it has no accepted answer.

@telcoM thanks for confirming.

Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI/gpt mode since 2012 and release of Windows 8. Better to convert Ubuntu to UEFI boot. Its just a different version of grub. You use grub-pc for BIOS and grub-efi-amd64 for UEFI boot. You can even have very old MBR and UEFI boot with Ubuntu, where Windows always requires gpt. But better to use gpt, just because it is better.

No, I'm just finishing windows10 mbr installation. Btw, ubuntu? No, I use arch btw. And no, I wanted to move to uefi, but i have too mamy custom initrd scripts and workflows. I will wait few more years. Also issues with zfs. I want boot partition to be in raid1, is that posiible? I have no reason at this time to use gpt.

You can use the old MBR. If drive is over 2TB, then you need gpt. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Partitioning#Choosing_between_GPT_and_MBR
